# Send/Receive Data between Native Android and Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to exchange data between a native android application and a phonegap application, how is this possible?

I've been reading the developers' guide: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html and I'm wondering if this is supported to a phonegap/cordova application and how (e.g. via a cordova-plugin)

I have been searching for some cordova-plugin buy I have only found out the [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) which partially does what I need for my use case

Simply put, what I need is to do some processing of some data and send them to another android application installed to the same device and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tutorial you provided, it seems that an intent with a given action (for example ACTION_SEND) and a given mime type (for example text/plain) can only share data with applications which have the same action and mime type (in our example, ACTION_SEND and text/plain).

So from a quick Google search, I discovered the following plugin which seemignly allows you to set a mime type and an action for Cordova applications when running on the Android platform. (I have not tried it myself).

https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much ThomCunningham I will give it a try and if it suits my use case I will let you know